# Vertical scroll affects min-width property

Tags: html, css

With min-width property set for `360px` if horizontal scroll appears it will make vertical scroll appear on window width value more than `360px`. Is there a way to change this without substracting pixels to min-width?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-breeze-51zie?file=/src/styles.css).

Css:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.App {
  min-width: 360px;
}
```

Reason: let's assume you want to support only devices width screen width more that 360px. You set min-width to 360px, but because of vertical scrollbar, horizontal scrollbar appears when screen width is ~360-370px;

Comment: Can you make your issue/requirement more clear?

Comment: @Nitheesh horizontal scroll bar should appear only when window size is les than 360px;

Comment: If you don't want to show the horizontal scroll bar you can do `overflow-x: hidden` on the html css selector. Also, a note on screen sizes, any device at that size; if a mobile device, wouldn't usually show the vertical scrollbar like it does in the browser.

Comment: @JakeB. i do want to show it for screens < 360px, but not for >360px

Comment: ok cool, this may work to not show horizontal scroll bars on screens above and including 360px, may need to set to 361px to avoid cross over; `@media(min-width:360px){html{overflow-x:hidden}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Valid approach is mobile-first - assuming smallest devices have less of memory, less of power. So, @media is for bigger.

Important - test it, you have much more css, and it can affect

```css
*, ::before, ::after { box-sizing: border-box;}
body{ margin: 0; height: 100%;}
.App{ max-width: 100%;}         /* this prevent horizontal scrolling */
@media and (min-width: 360px){  .App{ min-width: 360px}}

/* css for snippet only */
body{ background: #222; text-align: center}
div{ background: #fff; color: navy; margin: 5vh auto;  overflow: auto;  padding: 2vh 0; }
div div{ background: red; color: gold}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px">300px x auto<div class="App">.App</div></div>
<div style="width: 360px">360px x auto<div class="App">.App</div></div>
<div style="width: 400px">400px x auto<div class="App">.App</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add  `overflow: auto;`. when your screen is 360px and up it disapear.

```
.App {
  min-width: 360px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```